# SVN output path of the statistics

Tags: svn

I've find this very usefull sta-generator for SVN: [SVNstat](http://www.statsvn.org/)

I don't understand how to use it...i done these steps:

1. `svn log https://myHost:8443/svn/myFolder/trunk -v --xml > logfile.log`
2. `java -jar C:\mySVNpath\statsvn.jar C:\myLogPath\logfile.log`

This create the file in the same directory! i want to put it in a my folder. There are a fast way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try with this:

```
svn log https://myHost:8443/svn/myFolder/trunk -v --xml > logfile.log
java -jar C:\mySVNpath\statsvn.jar C:\myLogPath\logfile.log C:\outPutPath
```